# custom skin url in tinymce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I have a custom skin for tinymce to use in a wordpress site. And i would like to put the skin in different location than core wordpress files so that wordpress update would not break anything:
from

```
wp-includes/js/tinymce/themes/advanced/skins/myskin
```

to

```
wp-content/themes/mytheme/skins/myskin
```

i tried

```
skin_url: '/path to my skin/'
```

in tinymce init. but it isnt working.
Would be great help if anyone have idea of what i am missing